# Slide-over fixed position element not visible unless browser window resize

Tags: jquery, css, web-applications, mobile

I'm mimicking the slide-over style movement of a Mobile app, and am running into an issue. When a hidden, off-screen `<section>` slides onto screen, any of the elements which were set to `position:fixed` remain invisible unless I resize the browser frame.

I have tried applying a `$("section.current").children().show(0);` but that seem to have no effect - I'm still forced to resize the browser and the elements immediately appear.

If the elements have `position:absolute` or `position:relative` applied, the issue doesn't occur. Only with `position:fixed`

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: HTML or a demo, please. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: As potential fix, I removed the fixed positioning on the style sheet, and then add it back in once the animation is complete. It's a dirty fix, but it works. This just seems to be a bug with jQuery.

Comment: Can you link the bug for other users and answer your own question?